# BlockingQueue and releasing threads from waiting

Tags: java, multithreading, collections, blockingqueue

Suppose I have BlockingQueue and some of the threads are called take() but the queue is empty at the moment. And suppose I somehow know that in the future new elements will not appear in the queue. How can I release those threads that are called take() from waiting? Thanks!

```
  public void run() {
        //noinspection InfiniteLoopStatement
        while (true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(millisecondsToSleep);
                if (!kitchen.processedOrdersEmpty()) {
                    Order processedOrder = kitchen.getFromProcessedOrders();
                    kitchen.printMessage("took order#" + processedOrder.getOrderNumber());
                    Thread.sleep(millisecondsToServe);
                    kitchen.printMessage("served order#" + processedOrder.getOrderNumber());
                } else {
                    int currentRandom = getNextRandom();
                    if (currentRandom <= 10) {
                        Order newOrder = new Order(kitchen.getLastOrderNumber());
                        kitchen.puIntoUnprocessedOrders(newOrder);
                        kitchen.printMessage("generated new order#" + newOrder.getOrderNumber());
                    } else {
                        Thread.sleep(millisecondsToSleep);
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

where kitchen.getFromProcessedOrders() equals:

```
public Order getFromProcessedOrders() throws InterruptedException {
    return processedOrders.take();
}
```

and processedOrders is a BlockingQueue

Comment: Will you show us your code which u created already?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5378391/closing-a-blocking-queue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html)-

> A BlockingQueue does not intrinsically support any kind of "close" or
>   "shutdown" operation to indicate that no more items will be added. The
>   needs and usage of such features tend to be implementation-dependent.
>   For example, a common tactic is for producers to insert special
>   end-of-stream or poison objects, that are interpreted accordingly when
>   taken by consumers.

You should interrupt the thread where it is blocked -

```
public void run() {
        //noinspection InfiniteLoopStatement
        while (true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(millisecondsToSleep);
                if (!kitchen.processedOrdersEmpty()) {
                    Order processedOrder = kitchen.getFromProcessedOrders();
                    kitchen.printMessage("took order#" + processedOrder.getOrderNumber());
                    Thread.sleep(millisecondsToServe);
                    kitchen.printMessage("served order#" + processedOrder.getOrderNumber());
                } else {
                    int currentRandom = getNextRandom();
                    if (currentRandom <= 10) {
                        Order newOrder = new Order(kitchen.getLastOrderNumber());
                        kitchen.puIntoUnprocessedOrders(newOrder);
                        kitchen.printMessage("generated new order#" + newOrder.getOrderNumber());
                    } else {
                        Thread.sleep(millisecondsToSleep);
                    }
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) { 
                //... handle ...
            }catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

1) You can interrupt the thread where take() is running

2) You can put a special object to the queue as a signal of the end. If a thread gets a special object (END) it puts it back and exits, so other waiting threads will get END too.

Comment: 3) Set a volatile boolean indicating that the thread should exit.

Comment: @jontro  That doesnt help if three threads try to take from a queue with size of 2.  The third thread will wait indefinitely

Comment: @JohnVint yes. Depends on your strategy. My comment wouldnt apply here as I look at the code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can add some dummy record like `new String("##EOQ##")` to signify End of Queue and stop consumer threads.