# How to make SwingWorker wait for threads started from within this SwingWorker

Tags: java, swingworker

I have problem with `SwingWorker` and it's `done()` method. I have an application that supports plugins through SPI, so I basically can't change the behavior of the plugins. The interface these plugins have to implement contains method `List<T> getContracts()`. This is the method I am calling from `SwingWorker`'s `doInBackground()` method. But some of the plugins use multiple threads in this `getContracts()` method. The problem is, that the `done()` method is then called before these threads finish. Is there a way to make `SwingWorker` thread not to finish (not to call it's `done()` method) until all the threads called from this `SwingWorker` stop?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: How can `getContracts` return the list when the threads are still running?  Usually `doInBackground` would wait until all `getContracts` are done before exiting and calling `done`.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but it obviously doesn't wait. Individual threads add items to the list that is returned after all threads finished, so I have no idea how `SwingWorker` can finish before these threads

Comment: If you can get a handle on the worker threads you could Thread.join() them.

Comment: I hope that list is synchronized.  What's SPI? Google gives many different SPI's.  You should look at the api: as @extraneon said, if you could get the threads, you could join.  There might be other threading methods too.

Comment: SPI is servis provider interface, thanxs for you help guys, I'll try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you should just be wrapping [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250643/java-how-to-wait-for-all-threads-to-finish) question in your SwingWorker done() method.

Comment: In fact, there are several interesting answers there.  I like the accepted one because it is straightforward, and the one by sjlee, where you get a list of Futures because you could SwingWorker.publish() the Futures as they come back, updating your GUI incrementally if you wanted.

Comment: Actually I should be wrapping that in the plugin whose `getContracts` method I use (and since I am the creator of that plugin, I did it :) ) thank you