# ExecutorService.getActiveCount return approximate number of active threads

Tags: java, executorservice, threadpoolexecutor

i have read the documentation its mentioned that this method

`((ThreadPoolExecutor) executorService).getActiveCount();`

returns approximate  number of threads that are actively executing tasks.
can anyone suggest in which practical scenario this method will return incorrect count?
the reason why i asked this question is in my spring-boot app one of the UT case is dependent on this method and that ut cases is failing once in while specifically on Jenkins server.

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
SynchronousQueue<Integer> queue = new SynchronousQueue<>();
for(int i = 0;i<10;i++){
            executorService.submit(() -> {
                queue.put(1);
                return null;
            });
        }
```

what i am expecting is when i call this method `((ThreadPoolExecutor) executorService).getActiveCount();` it should not return 10 (number of running thread) instead it should return some other value may be 9 or 8 ..

Comment: For exact number you probably need to implement manual counting, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7271541/threadpoolexecutors-getactivecount

Comment: It can never be guaranteed to be exact, because tasks could be started or stopped concurrently with reading the value.