# Multiple Async Tasks for post in same activity

Tags: android, android-asynctask

i wrote those threads:
[How to manage multiple Async Tasks efficiently in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9221343/how-to-manage-multiple-async-tasks-efficiently-in-android)
[Running multiple AsyncTasks at the same time -- not possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068984/running-multiple-asynctasks-at-the-same-time-not-possible/4072832#4072832)

but didnt find answer for my question, maybe someone can help..

I have android app which makes Login POST and getting json response,
if the Json is OK i need to POST another data to get another response.

i have extends Async Class which doing the post to the URL:

```
public class AsyncHttpPost extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    private HashMap<String, String> mData = null;

    public AsyncHttpPost(HashMap<String, String> data) {
        mData = data;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        byte[] result = null;
        String str = "";
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(params[0]);// in this case, params[0] is URL
        try {
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            Iterator<String> it = mData.keySet().iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                String key = it.next();
                nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair(key, mData.get(key)));
            }

            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair, "UTF-8"));
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
                result = EntityUtils.toByteArray(response.getEntity());
                str = new String(result, "UTF-8");
            }
        }
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
        return str;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        try {
            JSONArray Loginjson = new JSONArray(result);
            strStt = Loginjson.getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("fields").getString("status");
            if (strStt.equals("ERR")) {
                ErrorMsg("Authentication failed");
            } else if (strStt.equals("OK")) {
                ErrorMsg("Login OK!!!");
                ClientPage();
            } else {
                ErrorMsg("Connection Error");
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            ErrorMsg("Connection Error");
        }       
    }
}
```

Now - i need to get another POST if the status is Error. do i need to make another Async class? with the same all procedures ? the issue is only the onPostExecute part is different.. actually the "doInBackground" will be always the same..

any idea how can i easily do multiple posts in the same activity?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, since your `doInBackground()` code will always stay the same, I recommend you move it into a general utility class.

Beyond that, you can go one of two ways:

1. Create a new AsyncTask for each type of request that can call your utility class, and have its own `onPostExecute()`
2. Create one AsyncTask that has a flag in it, which can be checked in the `onPostExecute()` method to see what code needs to be executed there. You will have to pass the flag in in the constructor or as a parameter in execute.

Comment: how can i move the background to general utility class if i need it to be asynctask? the main thread cannot use network, no?

also - can i just get the string from the response as return value and use it on the parent function instead the onPostExecute?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a parameter at `AsyncHttpPost` constructor/execute or global variable to indicate if it is first or second POST (by other words - a flag). Then just create and execute another instance of `AsyncHttpPost` in `onPostExecute` (only if parameter/variable is set as *"first POST"*).

Comment: Got it, but i still have multiple classes of async extented in my activity, right? I have no way to do the onpostexecute on the main function? I mean if i could get the response back to the main i will do the checks there instead the onpostexecute...

Comment: No, you can have only one asynctask extended class. Pass a parameter into its constructor and execute different parts of code depending on this parameter.