# Waiting for multiple Callbacks to occur before proceeding

Tags: java, android, firebase, callback

I am adding data to a map by using a loop which has a callback inside it. I am then passing this map to a Recycler View, but when I do this - the map is empty so nothing is shown. I assume it is because I need to wait for the callbacks to occur?

The loop below is within a class that's called from OnActivityCreated inside my fragment. Here's how my callbacks occur:

```
    for (final Map.Entry<String, UserDetails> entry : listOfUsers.entrySet()) {
        getSeasonsData("Seasons", entry.getKey(), new CallBack3() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(List<UserSeasons> seasons) {
                userSeasons.put(entry.getKey(), seasons);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(String error) {

            }

        });
    }
```

How can I wait for all the callbacks to complete within this loop before progressing?

Here is my getSeasonsData method:

```
 private void getSeasonsData(String pathString, String childNode, final CallBack3 callBack) {
    fbDB.child(pathString).child(childNode).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            List<UserSeasons> usersSeasonsListTemp = new ArrayList<>();

            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {

                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    UserSeasons C = ds.getValue(UserSeasons.class);
                    usersSeasonsListTemp.add(C);
                }
                callBack.onSuccess(usersSeasonsListTemp);

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            callBack.onError(databaseError.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You should overload `getSeasonsData` to take a list of entries, then return one callback

Comment: try passing `map` to `RecyclerView` in your `onSuccess` method.

Comment: @cricket_007 I've added my getSeasonsData method to the question. Could you please explain how I can do that with regards to my case here?

Comment: Well, the fact that you are using Firebase and have `addValueEventListener` within a nested loop. I know that is an anti-pattern, but I cannot answer how to fix it

Comment: In other words, the `onDataChange` is intended for realtime access of always changing data. You set the listener, and it always updates data, and that callback is ran. By sticking that in a loop, you are continuously overriding the listener. While the single query pattern is supported for lookups, this pattern indicates you need to restructure your database

Comment: That would take some time. But in terms of a quick fix, will the solution of using a counter work, as in your answer below? Would it be possible to adapt that having seen the getSeasonsData method now?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Waiting for multiple callbacks in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17418194/waiting-for-multiple-callbacks-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Firebase, I think you need to restucture your query or database.

For example, start from `fbDB.child(pathString)`, then you can get `childNode` and all other children at that path from the snapshot that is returned. With the information from `listOfUsers`, you should be able to filter the snapshot children, or accumulate a larger dataset and return the full data you need rather than executing multiple queries at several paths.

**Original Answer**

In theory, you could have some `int counter = 0;` and  `final int userSize = listOfUsers.size()`, then place an `if` statement somewhere in the callback for when `(i == userSize - 1)` to indicate that all events have been processed.

However, I suggest your function look like this. Internalizing the loop.

```
    getSeasonsData("Seasons", listOfUsers, new Callback() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Map<String, List<UserSeasons>> seasonMap) {
            // Loop over seasonMap  
            // seasons = seasonMap.get(entry.getKey());
            // userSeasons.put(entry.getKey(), seasons);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(String error) {

        }

    });
}
```

Within `public void getSeasonsData(String arg1, List arg2, Callback arg3)`, you can loop over the list, performing *blocking* network calls to add to some `Map<String, List<UserSeasons>>`, from which you return via the callback.

---

You could also have the entire Firebase callback rather than relying on your own.

```
private void getSeasonsData(String pathString, final ValueEventListener callBack) {
    fbDB.child(pathString).addValueEventListener(callBack);
}
```

...

```
// final Map listOfUsers = ... ;
getSeasonsData("Seasons", new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        List<UserSeasons> usersSeasonsListTemp = new ArrayList<>();

        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {

            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                // For example...
                // Object someData = ds.getValue(...);
                // if (listOfUsers.containsKey(someData.getID())) { }
```

Here, I removed the second parameter because if you really need it, you can do `"Seasons/" + key` because Firebase supports path query strings

Comment: I understand that I should change the structure of the query or FB database. But while it's in this state, is there a quick fix to just wait for all callbacks to occur?

Comment: I've given you three alternative options here. I don't know how to write it in order to get the data you're expecting

Answer (score 0):

The network call can take time so you don't expect the data to be ready before you create your RecycleView adapter. I suggest you setup your adapter with an empty dataset, then in the onSuccess callback you update your dataset and notify the adapter. You can do this by adding a new method to update the dataset in your RecyclerView adapter.