# Strange concurrent code behavior

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm currently in the process of learning Java concurrency. And I am very surprised by the way following code behaves.

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class Exercise {
    static int counter = 0;

    static synchronized int getAndIncrement() {
        return counter++;
    }

    static class Improper implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 300; i++) {
                getAndIncrement();
            }
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
        for (int i = 0; i < 300; i++) {
            executorService.submit(new Improper());
        }
        executorService.shutdown();
        System.out.println(counter);
    }
}
```

Shouldn't it output 90000 all the time? Instead the result differs all the time.

Comment: Try using `AtomicInteger`.

Comment: Think, you just have to await termination of ExecutorService http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250643/how-to-wait-for-all-threads-to-finish-using-executorservice

Answer (score 25, accepted):

1. `executorService.shutdown()` doesn't wait for the service to shut down. You need a call to `awaitTermination`.
2. you access the `counter` from the main method without locking. I think you would narrowly escape a data race if you waited for the executor service to shut down, but be warned that, in general, you must synchronize on all *accesses* of a shared variable, not just writes, to have any visibility guarantees from the Java Memory Model.

Comment: does it help to make counter volatile?

Comment: It does, but once again, it won't allow you to remove synchronization of the writing part. So you'll need both.

Comment: @bvk256 - Given that you are already using `synchronized`, it would be better to write a synchronized getter method to fetch the final result.  (Use of `synchronized` *and* a `volatile` variable is potentially inefficient.)

Comment: It will slow down the writing procedure with a doubled amount of memory barriers. On the other hand, it will speed up the reading due to a *halved* amount of memory barriers.

Answer (score 3):

You need to make sure that all tasks have had time to terminate. Use [`awaitTermination`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#awaitTermination%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
    for (int i = 0; i < 300; i++) {
        executorService.submit(new Improper());
    }
    executorService.shutdown();
    executorService.awaitTermination(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    System.out.println(counter);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't wait for all your submited tasks to terminate, see the javadoc for [ExecutorService.html#shutdown](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown%28%29). So gettting an arbitrary output each time is the expected behabiour.