# Java - Multithreading a Raytracer Loop

Tags: java, multithreading, raytracing

I am trying to parallelize the raytracer im currently working on for university, but i cant quite seem to get it to work. Ive tried multiple implementations, but the problem stays the same.rendering stops after a few milliseconds and at most a small chunk of the picture is rendered.

```
    final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int i = 0; i < image.getWidth(); i++) {
        final int ii =i;
        executor.execute(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                for (int j = 0; j < image.getHeight(); j++) {
                    raster.setDataElements(ii, image.getHeight()-j-1, model.getDataElements(
                            getPixelColor(width,height,ii,j,world,pcameras2),0, null));
                }
            }
        });
    }
    g.drawImage(this.image, 0, 0, this);
    System.out.println("Rednering finished in: " + (System.currentTimeMillis()-start)/1000.0 + " seconds");
}
public static float[] getPixelColor(final int width,final int height,
        final int x,final int y,final World world,final Camera camera){
    final Hit hit = world.hit(camera.rayFor(width,height, x, y));
    if(hit != null){
        return new float[]{(float) hit.geo.material.ColorFor(hit,world).r,
                (float) hit.geo.material.ColorFor(hit,world).g,(float) hit.geo.material.ColorFor(hit,world).b, 1};
    } else {
        return new float[]{(float) world.backgroundColor.r, (float) world.backgroundColor.g, (float) world.backgroundColor.b, 1};
    }
}
```

I found out, that if i exlude the world.hit() method it works just fine, but as this contains most of the computation, thats not an option.

Comment: `executor.execute` returns immediately and you can not expect that the asynchronous computation is already finished at that point. The image can't be complete. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250643/how-to-wait-for-all-threads-to-finish-using-executorservice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1250655/2228771), you want to call `shutdown` to tell the Exector to shutdown *after all currently queued tasks* have been finished, and then `awaitTermination` to wait until they are all done.

```
executor.shutdown();
try {
    executor.awaitTermination(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // what should happen if timeout was hit
}

// image is complete here (if InterruptedException was not thrown)
g.drawImage(this.image, 0, 0, this);
```