# What API can I use to to await the completion of tasks

Tags: java, multithreading

What i need is a tool/class that acts like [CoundDownLatch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) but can be counted up and down. Whenever a task is executed it will counted up, when a task is done it is counted down. There can be multiple tasks running parallel, and one thread should wait until no task is executing/ the counter is at 0.

I looked into the [Phaser](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Phaser.html) class, but i don't know if it provides what i am looking for, maybe it can be used to solve this puzzle?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic, because you're requesting a third-party tool. You could store your threads in an array, and join on them to ensure they all complete before you exit. You might use [Future](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) to get the results, or you might do something else entirely. What design are you using, and where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition` together with `ReentrantLock` and `AtomicInteger`.

Pseudo code for task executor:

```
// start executing task
taskCounter.incrementAndGet();
// execute task
...
// stop executing task
if (taskCounter.decrementAndGet() == 0) {
    condition.signal();
}
```

Pseudo code for waiter thread:

```
condition.await();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use an [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) as discussed in [How to wait for all threads to finish, using ExecutorService?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1250643/823393).