# How to know whether there're running tasks in ExecutorService in java?

Tags: java

I'd like to allow the program continue until all the tasks in ExecutorService is done. And I don't want to shutdown it, I use it later. 
How can I achieve this ? 
Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250643/how-to-wait-for-all-threads-to-finish-using-executorservice

Answer (score 0):

Use `ExecutorService#shutdown()` followed by `ExecutorService#awaitTermination()` to make your `main` thread wait for all the submitted tasks to complete before it exits. From the docs for

[ExecutorService#awaitTermination()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#awaitTermination(long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit))

> Blocks until all tasks have completed execution after a shutdown request, or the timeout occurs, or the current thread is interrupted, whichever happens first.

Comment: Actually I don't want to shutdown it, I use it later

Answer (score 0):

An example taken directly from the `ExecutorService` Javadoc:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html

> The following method shuts down an ExecutorService in two phases, first by calling shutdown to reject incoming tasks, and then calling shutdownNow, if necessary, to cancel any lingering tasks:

```
void shutdownAndAwaitTermination(ExecutorService pool) {
  pool.shutdown(); // Disable new tasks from being submitted
  try {
    // Wait a while for existing tasks to terminate
    if (!pool.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
      pool.shutdownNow(); // Cancel currently executing tasks
      // Wait a while for tasks to respond to being cancelled
      if (!pool.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
          System.err.println("Pool did not terminate");
    }
  } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
    // (Re-)Cancel if current thread also interrupted
    pool.shutdownNow();
    // Preserve interrupt status
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
  }
}
```