# Stop loop execution while Thread executing

Tags: java, multithreading

I have loop like:

```
for(final TestCase tc : tcPool) {

                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        runTCCmd(tc.createJavaClass());
                    }
                }).start();

            }
```

**How can I freeze(stop) loop on time while `new Thread(...)` executing??**

I used `ExecutorService`before but it did not stop thread execution:

```
private ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

this.executorService.submit(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                       runTCCmd(tc.createJavaClass());
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Declare a flag in Thread  say like boolean running = true;. Add while(runnig) in the run method and make running=false whenever you want

Comment: there is an answer for ExecutorService case: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1250655/1233521

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        runTCCmd(tc.createJavaClass());
    }
});
t.start();
t.join();
```

Comment: If _this_ is what OP was actually about, then clearly the whole shebang should have been replaced with just `runTCCmd(tc.createJavaClass());` Why on earth would someone create another thread, then _unconditionally_ wait for that thread to die before going on?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use single thread executor?
It will execute the tasks sequentially.

```
private ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
for(final TestCase tc : tcPool) {
      executorService.submit(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
              runTCCmd(tc.createJavaClass());
          }
      });
}
executorService.shutdown();
executorService.awaitTermination(shutdownTimeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
```