# java Multithreading - throttle submission to ExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, futuretask

I have a data file with thousand of rows. I am reading them and saving them in the database. I want to multi-thread this process in the batches of say 50 
rows. As I am read in the file, 10 rows are submitted to an ExecutorService.

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);`
```

I can do below in a in a while loop till my rows end....

```
 Future<Integer> future = executor.submit(callableObjectThatSaves10RowsAtOneTime);
```

But, I don't want to read the entire file into memory if the processing 10 rows is taking time. I only want to submit 5 till one of the threads return, then I submit the next.

Let's say a thread takes 20 seconds to save the 10 records, I don't want the `ExecutorService` to be fed thousand of lines since the reading process is continuing to read and submit to ExecutorService

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250643/how-to-wait-for-all-threads-to-finish-using-executorservice

Comment: @Cratylus this is definitely not a duplicate of the question you linked. The OP is asking how to throttle the number of tasks submitted to avoid having to read a huge file all at once, not how to know when all tasks are completed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a `LinkedList<Future<?>>` that stores futures until you've reached some pre-determined size. Here's some skeleton code that should get you most of the way there:

```
int threads = 5;
ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threads);
LinkedList<Future<?>> futures = new LinkedList<>();

//As long as there are rows to save:
while(moreRowsLeft()){
    //dump another callable onto the queue:
    futures.addLast(service.submit(new RowSavingCallable());

    //if the queue is "full", wait for the next one to finish before
    //reading any more of the file:
    while(futures.size() >= 2*threads) futures.removeFirst().get();
}

//All rows have been submitted but some may still be writing to the DB:
for(Future<?> f : futures) future.get();

//All rows have been saved at this point
```

You may wonder why I've allowed the number of futures to reach twice the number of threads on the machine - this allows executor service threads to be working on database saves while the main thread is creating more work to be done. This can help hide any I/O cost associated with making more callables available for processing while the worker threads are busy doing the Database write.

Comment: @CodeBlind- Thank you! I do have a question. Shouldn't we start removing from first element of the LinkList. The first one that was added to the LinkedList would have a higher chance of being returned first after completing the task? Can we potentially plug in  ExecutorService.take() to your algorithm and optimize?

Comment: @Giovanny yes, you're right, a typo on my part :) I've fixed it.  As for plugging in `ExecutorCompletionService.take()` - seems reasonable to me. You could just use a counter to keep track of how many you've submitted and call `take()` when you've exceeded some threshold.

Comment: The last loop will call the 'get' on the Futures that we had already called 'get' on. This will not do any additional process right ?