# how to tell if every Thread of a ThreadPool is waiting

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, threadpool, blockingqueue

i have a ThreadPool with a lot of threads.
the task is finished if every thread of this threadpool is waiting on a BlockingQueue. how can i figure out if every Thread is waiting so i can shutdown the threadpool?

Comment: How are you going to shut down the threadpool?

Comment: yeah thats another question... is there a possibility to terminate all waiting threads in a threadpool? or just to interrupt all threads in a threadpool?

Comment: BlockingQueue docs _A BlockingQueue does not intrinsically support any kind of "close" or "shutdown" operation to indicate that no more items will be added. The needs and usage of such features tend to be implementation-dependent. For example, a common tactic is for producers to insert special end-of-stream or poison objects, that are interpreted accordingly when taken by consumers._

Comment: so basically when you are done shoving processable items into the queue, you put in items that the receiving threads interpret as a signal to shut down.

Answer (score 0):

You should call `shutdown()` and then `awaitTermination()` with a long timeout value.  When the tasks are done, it will shutdown.

See this answer: [How to wait for all threads to finish, using ExecutorService?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250643/how-to-wait-for-all-threads-to-finish-using-executorservice)