# Communication between main thread and worker threads in android

Tags: android, multithreading, executorservice

In my very first android project, I do some data manipulation, so I use multi-threading approach.

In MainActivity, I created multiple Runnable object and use ExecutorService to run all the threads. As my understanding, all threads are put in message queue and executed in turn. And the because the main thread is already in the queue, it will be executed before starting other threads. Is there any way that I can make the main thread wait for other threads to finish and then continue?

```
   @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //call MyFunction here
}
private List<Pair[]> myFunction(int dataInput) throws InterruptedException {
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(12);
    MyTask MyTask = new MyTask();
    for (int i = 0; i < gallerySize; ++i) {
        final int index = i;
        Runnable runnable = MyTask.runLongOperationWithThread(new MyTask.DataCallback(){
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(double[] scores) {
                // get data back to main thread
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Exception ex) {
                //TODO: log this error out to file
            }
        });
        executorService.execute(runnable);
    }

    // try to get back all data from multi threading and do some operations
    return returnList;
}
```

Do Looper and Handler help in this case?

And please correct me if I have any misunderstanding in android concept and threading.

Thanks.

Comment: Activity has `runOnUiThread`. Also, Handlers can receive messages, and if they are running on the main thread Looper, the messages will be processed on the main thread. So basically read the doc: https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Android, stopping main thread is **discouraged**. The system will tell the user that the app is not responding. However, you can "notify" the main thread that the background thread has finished its work. Once the main thread knows this, it will do something. It is common in Android, it is what [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for.

However, `AsyncTask` is used for a simple one thread. In your case, one of the solution is to combine `ExecutorService` and `AsyncTask`. In `doInBackground` method of `AsyncTask` instance you make, use `ExecutorService` like usual, and wait it to finish by either `shutdown(); awaitTermination()` or `invokeAll()`. Read [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250643/how-to-wait-for-all-threads-to-finish-using-executorservice) for more information about how to wait `ExecutorService` to finish.

```
private class WrappingTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Exception> {
    protected Exception doInBackground(Void... args) {
        ExecutorService taskExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(12);
        for (. . .) {
            taskExecutor.execute(new MyTask(. . .));
        }
        taskExecutor.shutdown();
        try {
            taskExecutor.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            . . .
            return e;
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Exception error) {
        // Notify the user that the task has finished or do anything else
        // and handle error
    }
 }
```

**In case of long running task**

`AsyncTask` is a handy class to make threading and communicating (to main thread) easier. The problem for long running task is that the user can leave the `Activity` (and then come again), or there is an incoming call, etc. If you don't handle this *Activity lifecycle* with care, it is so "dangerous", `AsyncTask` does not handle this.

Long running task should be run in a [`Service`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html). Note that `Service` is also run in the main thread, so the approach would be the same, unless you use [`IntentService`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html). In case of `IntentService`, just execute all of the threads (formerly in `doInBackground`) in the `onHandleIntent` method and wait it there, this method is called on a worker thread.

Communicating `Service` with `Activity` and maintaining consistency of `Activity`'s state through its lifecycle is a long story. You better read the documentation in "a full concentration" with a cup of coffee :D. This might helps:

- [Managing the Activity Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html?hl=id)
- [Best Practices for Background Jobs](https://developer.android.com/training/best-background.html)

Comment: I read somewhere that asyncTask is not good enough for heavy data processing. In my case, because I work with large set of data and need to use parallel processing, does asyncTask can help to achieve the task?

Comment: @nghiduong90 AsyncTask is not good because it doesn't handle Activity lifecycle itself. You should handle it yourself. And it's better to use a Service instead of Activity. I've updated my answer.