# I can't wait my Threads in java

Tags: java, multithreading, wait

I have  problems in mulithreads environment . I can create several threads that execute correctly, However the process never end. I can't wait for the finishing.
I want to do some action when all my threads end but currently it is impossible. Here my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args){

 public void run(){
            ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
    try {
                for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
                    final Integer a=i;
                    try {
                        exec.submit(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                            public void run() {  

                        System.out.println(a);
                        }
                     });
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
}
```

Someone knows how to achieve my goal? Thanks!

Comment: Where do you call `notify()`?

Comment: Why are you creating a new thread pool inside of a Thread? You've already got a thread to execute on.

Comment: Also look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250643/how-to-wait-for-all-threads-to-finish-using-executorservice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't create a thread and an `ExecutorService`. That's redundant.

Currently, your program isn't exiting because the main thread called `wait()` but no other thread is calling `notify()`.

If you want the main thread to wait until all of the tasks finish, do something like this:

```
final class EjecutorUpdateContactos {
  void update() throws Exception {
    ExecutorService workers = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
    List<Callable<Void>> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      int a = i;
      tasks.add(new Callable<Void>() {
        @Override
        public Void call() {
          System.out.println(a);
          return null;
        }
      });
    }
    workers.invokeAll(tasks);
    workers.shutdown();
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
    public class EjecutorUpdateContactos extends Thread {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        try {
              for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
              final Integer a = i;
              try {
                   exec.submit(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                     public void run() {

                        System.out.println(a);
                    }
                });
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        notify();
    }
  }
}
```