# How to keep listening for tasks in executorservice

Tags: java, service

Say I have a queue full of tasks which I need to submit to an executor service. I want to process them in parallel. That's cover.

```
private ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
```

I recive 20 tasks to be executed, and all of there are processed as I expected in groups of 5.

```
service.execute(tasks.poll());
```

But now I want to keep adding tasks to the queue and process them as I do now, but the service finish after the 20 original tasks.

How can I do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250643/how-to-wait-for-all-threads-to-finish-using-executorservice

Comment: do you have the shutdown .Can you please update all code

Answer (score 0):

```
       executor.awaitTermination()
```

this will wait until all the tasks are completed, this should be using after executorl.shutdown()