# Java ForkJoinPool with .forEach and .add

Tags: java, arrays, spring-boot, threadpool, parallel.foreach

I have a List of `TicketDTO` objects where every `TicketDTO` needs to go through a function to convert the data to `TicketDataDTO`. What I want here is to reduce the time it takes for this code to run because when the list size is bigger, it takes a lot of time to convert it and it's unacceptable for fetching the data through a GET mapping. However, when I try to implement `ForkJoinPool` along with the `parallelStream)` (code below) to get it done, my return List` is empty. Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

```
@Override
public List<TicketDataDTO> getOtrsTickets(String value, String startDate, String endDate, String product, String user) {
  // TODO Implement threads
  List<TicketDTO> tickets = ticketDao.findOtrsTickets(value, startDate, endDate, product, user);
  Stream<TicketDTO> ticketsStream = tickets.parallelStream();
  List<TicketDataDTO> data = new ArrayList<TicketDataDTO>();
  
  ForkJoinPool forkJoinPool = new ForkJoinPool(6);
  
  forkJoinPool.submit(() -> {
    try {
      ticketsStream.forEach(ticket -> data.add(createTicketData(ticket)));
    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  });
  
  forkJoinPool.shutdown();
  
  //ticketsStream.forEach(ticket -> data.add(createTicketData(ticket)));

  return data;
```

`createTicketData` is just a function with two for loops and one switch loop to create some new columns I need as an output.

Comment: You're modifiying a single ArrayList from multiple threads without doing any kind of synchronization. Even once you fix your immediate issue this will result in errors. I recommend you read https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html and swap to using a non-side-effectful approach using `collect(Collectors.toList())`. Additionally the use of custom ForkJoinPools in parallel streams is not a supported feature. Better to explicitly call `ExecutorService.submit` or `invokeAll` to get a list of Futures and wait on them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Additional to calling `shutdown()` on the ForkJoinPool, you have to wait for its termination like

```
forkJoinPool.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
```

If you do not wait for the termination, `data` will be returned before the threads have the chance to add their results to it.

See
[How to wait for all threads to finish, using ExecutorService?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250643/how-to-wait-for-all-threads-to-finish-using-executorservice)
for more details